# How to migrate server group mule applications to cluster in mule 4?

Tags: mule4

We have domain applications deployed on Runtime Manager with 2 dev servers in a server group in Develop Environment and have one QA server in Test Environment.

Now, we are planning to migrate these QA server and DEV-Server group to Cluster in their respective environments.

I would like to know the procedure for migration of servers to cluster and its pros and cons.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't migrate applications, either between servers, clusters or any combination. You'll need to recreate the applications in the deployment target.